# Computing the GCD of two polynomials

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

I'm trying to find the $\gcd$ of 
$A:= x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1$ and 
$B:= x^2 + 2$.

Using the Euclidean algorithm, I've found

$$(x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1)=(x^2 - x - 1)(x^2 + 2) + (x + 3)$$

and

$$(x^2 + 2)=(x - 3)(x + 3) + 11$$

Do I then need to continue using the algorithm to get

\begin{align}
(x + 3)&=(x/11)(11) + 3\\
11 &= (3)(3) + 2\\
3 &= (1)(2) + 1 \\
2 &= (2)(1) \\
&\rightarrow  \gcd(A,B)=1
\end{align}

or is $\gcd(A,B) = (x + 3)$? As it is the last polynomial that is a common divisor of $A$ and $B$.

If the first case is true and the $\gcd(A,B) = 1$, what happens if the remainder is a fraction and not an integer?

Comment: i think the searched Gcd is one

Comment: Are you working in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ (or $\mathbb{Q}[x]$) or $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? If you are working with polynomials over a *field*, there are technically infinitely many gcd, for we can multiply by any unit. However, the convention is to use a monic polynomial.

Comment: I am working in Q[x]. Would this mean that the gcd is (x+3)?

Answer (score 0):

you given this polynomials $A=X^4-X^3+X^2-X+1$ and $B=X^2+2$.
Here $degree of B$ is smaller.And it cannot  factorize in $Q[X]$.
Hence try to divide $polynomial A$ by $polynomial B$.It is not completely divisible.
Hence $ gcd(A,B)=1$.
$x+3$ cannot be the answer.since it cannot completely divisible by $B$.